# Combine output of two different buttons

Tags: java

I am writing code for a vending machine and have a button layout of letters and numbers.

Right now, if I press the "a" button, it prints "a" into a box, but if I press the "1" button, it will replace the "a" that's already in the box and print "1" in its place. How can I make the output say "a1" instead of simply one or the other?

```
 String buttonText = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(event.getSource() == button[i]) { 
                    JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
                    String buttonText1 = clickedButton.getText();
                    buttonText += buttonText1;
                    itemSelection.setText(buttonText);
```

Comment: What's the type of `itemSelection`?

Comment: @Sybren itemSelection is a JTextField

Answer (score 2):

At a time you won't be able to click more than one button.
Instead of your this code:

```
String buttonText = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if(event.getSource() == button[i]) { 
                    JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
                    String buttonText1 = clickedButton.getText();
                    buttonText += buttonText1;
                    itemSelection.setText(buttonText);
```

Try this:

```
String buttonText = ((JButton) event.getSource()).getText();
itemSelection.setText(itemSelection.getText() + buttonText);
```

*Edited:*

In order to limit the input, try `DocumentFilter`.

Comment: any suggstions on how to limit the number of charcters that can be entered at once to 2? So if the user enters "B2" then types "c3," c3 will take  the place of B2

Answer (score 1):

use variables like String button1Choice,button2Choice. update them onclick and update your textfield like

```
textField.settext(button1Choice + button2Choice)
```

edit: you can also define your buttonText outside of the clickHandler which will then save its state, now your always starting with an empty String.

contra of this method: if a button is clicked twice, the text will appear twice and you have to implement a routine for resetting the choice

Comment: I updated the post with a snippet of code, can you help anymore?